# How to use variables across files in React JS

Tags: reactjs, api, react-props

So I have set two datepickers which needs to be reformatted to MM-YYYY which I done with the following code:

```
const [dateFrom, setDateFrom ] = useState('2012-01-01')
const [dateTill, setDateTill ] = useState('2012-12-31')

const [yearFrom, monthFrom, dayFrom] = dateFrom.split('-');
const newDateFrom = `${monthFrom}-${yearFrom}`
const [yearTill, monthTill, dayTill] = dateTill.split('-');
const newDateTill = `${monthTill}-${yearTill}`
export default {newDateFrom, newDateTill}
```

I want to use the newDateFrom and newDateTill variables in my api file located in my api folder. I have used string interpolation here.

export const fetchTimeData = async () => {

```
const response = await fetch(`https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?brewed_before=${newDateTill}&brewed_after=${newDateFrom}&per_page=80`)
const data = await response.json();

return data
```

}

How can I get this to work? I'm not sure if props would work as there isn't a parent-child relationship going on here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't call the `useState` function in the global scope; if you want the variables returned from `useState` to be accessible to other functions, you need to make a custom hook like the following:

```js
export function useNewDate() {
  const [dateFrom, setDateFrom ] = useState('2012-01-01')
  const [dateTill, setDateTill ] = useState('2012-12-31')

  const [yearFrom, monthFrom, dayFrom] = dateFrom.split('-');
  const newDateFrom = `${monthFrom}-${yearFrom}`
  const [yearTill, monthTill, dayTill] = dateTill.split('-');
  const newDateTill = `${monthTill}-${yearTill}`

  return {newDateFrom, newDateTill}
}
```

Then, because you're using hooks, your `fetchTimeData` also needs to be a hook:

```js
import { useNewDate } from './useNewDate' // or whichever file your useNewDate hook is stored in
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const useFetchTimeData = () => {
  const { newDateFrom, newDateTill } = useNewDate()
  const [timeData, setTimeData] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?brewed_before=${newDateTill}&brewed_after=${newDateFrom}&per_page=80`)
      const data = await response.json();
      setTimeData(data)
    })();
  }, [])

  return timeData
}
```

Then, whenever you want to fetch the time data from within a React component, you would import this hook:

```js
import { useFetchTimeData } from './useFetchTimeData'

export function MyComponent() {
  const timeData = useFetchTimeData();

  if (timeData === null) {
    return <div>Loading time data...</div>
  }

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(timeData)}</div>
}
```